# Reading a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, file, import

I am importing a text file database in my SQL server database in asp.net c#.
I cannot fetch the column name from .txt file which contains a numeric data.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: Not nearly enough information here to provide a sensible answer, but I imagine the column name is something you can pick and put hardcoded into the import routine, along with the table name.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  you have a text file that is an export of a database and you want to import this into sql server?  But the colomn names don't exist in your text file?

Comment: @Bhavesh, To make the question easier to answer, you could supply a small example text file and the definition of the table into which you are loading it.  Also, a sample of the code you have tried might be helpful.  

I look forward to answering your question after you have added these.  :)

Comment: I almost always use http://www.filehelpers.com/ for import/export of textfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the data type of the database column where u save text file to text or ntext.